# Map Controller Route Not Working on Razor Pages in Areas

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

Developing a new (but very large) asp.net 6 Core MVC web application. My first project using this environment (all others were in .NET Framework). Every step is a struggle to figure out (documentation does not work). Currently my struggle is the ability to browse Razor pages in an Area. I have multiple Areas with Controllers (just like in .NET Framework does). I cannot map my endpoints correctly so that the pages can be browsed. I believe that there is a way to configure the Program.cs so that .NET Core 6 will do all the work for me. Any advice would be great.

This is my file structure in my project (see attached):

Cannot browse to the Manage/Events/Index page..

Below is a code snippet from my Program.cs file (see attached).

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages(); //Routes for pages
    endpoints.MapControllers(); //Routes for my API controllers

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "default",
      pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "Admin",
      pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "AreaManage",
        areaName: "Manage",
        pattern: "Manage/{controller=Events}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

It should not be difficult to figure this out! Lots of documentation but noting works..
[image]

Comment: Have you added `[Area("Manage")]` to your events controller?

Comment: That seem to have resolved it, however I still have to list all the controllers in the area in the program.cs. There has to be a better way so that .net core will automatically map the controller routes without having to list them all separately as i illustrated in my code sample?

thanks for the help as I did not read one article that indicated that I had to decorate my controller class in my area as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to list route template for every area controller in the Program.cs.

If the route template to access your area is like:

`/{AreaName}/{Controller}/{Action}/{Parameters?}`

You just need to use one route template to match all area in your project:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "MyArea",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

In the preceding code, exists applies a constraint that the route must match an area. Using {area:...} with MapControllerRoute:

- Is the least complicated mechanism to adding routing to areas.
- Matches all controllers with the [Area("Area name")] attribute.

In general, routes with areas should be placed earlier in the route table as they're more specific than routes without an area.

Comment: Can you please further explain you example:

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "MyArea",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Are you saying that this line of code will grab all the controllers in my area as I add them to the project? If so then why does your example include "controller=Home"?

I would think there is a way to configure the api so it will look up all controllers in the Area?

Comment: `{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}` means when the url don't specified the controller and action, it will default map to home controller and index action. If url specified controller and action, It will map to the correct controller and action. I strongly recommend to read this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#route-templates).